# Change the state directly when using a useState

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I'm new to React native and I'm experimenting to understand some things. Below I can update the state with onPress1. When I press onPress2 I get a "read-only" error. But in onPress3 it doesn't give an error even though it updates the status directly. It changes the whole state in onPress2 and onPress3. If state was a variable, changing it directly would cause a "read-only" error. Why doesn't it give an error when I change only the first element or all elements of an object one by one? Also, to replace only 1 element of an existing array, is it okay if I directly replace only 1 element, similar to onPress3?

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native'

let data = [
  { word: "Strong" },
  { word: "Support" }
]

export default function WordSelect() {

  const [list, setList] = useState(data)

  const onPress1 = () => {
    setList([
      { word: "Together" },
      { word: "Drunk" }
    ])
  }

  const onPress2 = () => {
    list = [
      { word: "Together" },
      { word: "Drunk" }
    ]
  }

  const onPress3 = () => {
    list[0] = {  word: "Together" }
    list[1] = {  word: "Drunk" }
  }

  return (
    <View style={{paddingTop:50}}>
      <Button title='onPress1' onPress={()=>{onPress1()}}></Button>
      <Button title='onPress1' onPress={()=>{onPress2()}}></Button>
      <Button title='onPress1' onPress={()=>{onPress3()}}></Button>
      <Text>{list[0].word} </Text>
      <Text>{list[1].word} </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Don't mutate state directly. Update the state via the `setList` function. Otherwise the component will not rerender with the updated state.

Answer (score 0):

`list` is a `const` so doing `list = something` will throw an error, that's why `onPress2` crashes.

`onPress3` doesnt throw an error because you are not reassigning `list` itself. Doing :

```
const a = {b:1}
a.b = 2
```

is fine and will update `a.b`.

Note that you should always use `setList` to update your `list`. Only `onPress1` has a correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As per ReactJS documentation you can only change the value of state by using the call back function that is `setList` in provided code. So basically you have to mutate the value of state via the function `setList`.

Please [click here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) for more clarification.